# Is there a way to put this in an array .txt file?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

Example 1

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == 'name1' || $_SESSION['username'] == 'name2') {
```

Is it possible to put the names in an .txt file so it reads the txt file for names instead of the above?

***Edit***

Example 2

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] = array("file.txt") ) {
```

Note that I understand that the above code doesn't work that way, but it's just to explain what I'm trying to do here.

I want to add users to file.txt, so I don't need to add users like example 1.

Comment: Probably, sure, just concatenate. However, it's a bit unclear what you're asking; give us an example

Comment: @Fred-ii- Is there a way for the script to read an .txt file with the names in it, instead of `$_SESSION['username'] == '' |` everytime I need to add a new name? Just so it's easier to add users to the list.

Comment: lordie, I don't know, something like assigning it first `$_SESSION['username'] = "file.txt";`? then pass that to your conditional statement after. if that's what the question is about

Comment: @Fred-ii- That works? I just need to add one time the $_SESSION and the text file? In that text file, I just need to separate the names with a enter, right?

Comment: sorry Willy, I'm (still) having difficulty trying to figure out what the ultimate goal here is. You mean you want to add/write the session array(s) to a text file?

Comment: real men us db's over txt file

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, you're on the right path, my warrior. I try to grab the names of the user from an .txt file so I don't have to add the names separately in the script itself, I want to add the names to the .txt file.

Comment: I've posted something for you below. If that doesn't work the way you want it to, I'll try and modify it, but I have to leave for about 1/2 hour. *Give it a whirl*.

Comment: @WillyWybert Your question is unclear. What do you want? Do you want to write to a file now or read a file?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I added an better example to my OP.

Comment: ok I'm back. Well, far as I can tell by your edit, is pretty much what my answer does. The `a` switch keeps adding to a file with a name under it, or if you use the `w` switch, it will overwrite it, so I don't think that's what you want to do.

Comment: or is the question about checking if there is already a (session) name already in a given file?

Comment: well I've done the best I could with this question. Reload my answer and look under **Edit #2:** Check if a name exists in a file. If that doesn't answer the question, you'll need to wait for another answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm grasping the question here correctly, but try the following.

This will append to a file each time and giving a result like this for example:
(after loading the script twice)

```
name1
name1
```

and the filename will be called the same name as the session name, for example `name1.txt`.

The `a` switch is to append. You can use `w` switch to write once and overwrite any previous content.

```
<?php 

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "name1";
if ( 
isset($_SESSION['username']) 

&& $_SESSION['username'] == 'name1' 
|| $_SESSION['username2'] == 'name2'
) 

{

$session_file = $_SESSION['username'] . "\n";
$filename = $_SESSION['username'];

     $file = fopen($filename.".txt", 'a');

     fwrite($file, $session_file);

     fclose($file);

}
```

---

**Edit:**

This version will write out two different session names, one underneath the other:

```
name1
name2
```

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['username1'] = "name1";
$_SESSION['username2'] = "name2";

if ( isset($_SESSION['username1']) 
|| isset($_SESSION['username2']) 

&& $_SESSION['username1'] == 'name1' 
|| $_SESSION['username2'] == 'name2') 

{

$_POST['html'] = "<b>content</b>";

$_POST['fileName'] = "filename1";

$session1 = $_SESSION['username1'] . "\n";
$session2 = $_SESSION['username2'] . "\n";
$session3 = $session1.$session2;
$filename = $_SESSION['username'];

     $file = fopen($filename.".php", 'a');
     fwrite($file, $session3);
     fclose($file);

}
```

---

**Edit #2**: Check if a name exists in a file.

If you wish to see if a name already exists in a file.

*Sidenote:* The `b` is for "word boundary" and `i` is for case-insensitive for [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
<?php 
session_start();
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Cannot open file!\n");

$_SESSION['username'] = "name_X";

$search = $_SESSION['username'];

 while ($line = fgets($file, 1024)) { 

    if (preg_match("/\b$search\b/i", $line)) { 

        echo "<b>Found match: " . $line . "</b>" . " - Stopping script.";

exit; // Stop the script from going any further.

    } 

}

echo "Name not found, writing to file...";

// rest of code
```

Comment: upvote for comprehensive answer that should be portable to other languages as basic idea (versus `file` which just happens to achieve the same thing as pre-existing native function in PHP).

Comment: @Anthony Thank you Anthony, I appreciate the comment/upvote, *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are storing usernames in a text file like:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

and your goal is to check that the value set in `$_SESSION['username']` is in the text file, you could use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) like:

```
 $user_list = file("users.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
 if ( isset($_SESSION['username'] ) && in_array($_SESSION['username'], $user_list ) ) {}
```

Comment: This looked promising when I saw this and I tested it and threw `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ',' or ')'...` - You'll want to check the brackets. Change that to `if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && in_array($_SESSION['username'], $user_list ) )` and it will work as intended.

Comment: I'm also hoping that the OP will respond to any of the answers given; seems like they've vanished into thin air.

Comment: I think I already caught that and fixed example (copy/paste error). Does the current example still throw errors?

Comment: Yes Anthony, that's the one I tested it with; same error.

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && in_array($_SESSION['username'], $user_list) )` is what it should be and I have tested it; worked like a charm ;-)

Comment: Oh der. Fixed. There are a number of problems/questions the OP's question raises (like is this a good idea? How is the txt file being managed? Are they asking how to both create/update txt or just how to pull in text file as array? etc) But as far as the most simple interpretation of the question goes, `file` is the way to go if the text file is simple newline-separated list.

Comment: Yeah, the OP's question was unclear from the beginning and it still is, far as I'm concerned. Oh well, I tried. *Cheers* - Nice one-liner btw. I upvoted your answer. P.s.: I'm not expecting an upvote just because I said this, just giving credit where credit is due ;-) Good job.